# Insert bs modal on page just by using JS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a wrapper function for Bootstrap Modal, I have gone through the actual modal function definition but I am unable to figure out how to instantiate a Modal by using JS.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal"></div> <!--I DON'T WISH TO HAVE ANYTHING ELSE ON THE PAGE-->
```

JS:

```
var BSModal = {};

BSModal.create = function(options) {
  var modal = new Modal($('.modal'), options);  //THROWS ERROR, Modal not defined.

  ...

}.bind(BSModal);
```

How do I properly instantiate the modal? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js

> $.fn.modal.Constructor = Modal

so i believe you can use something like this in your code

```
var modal = new $.fn.modal.Constructor($('.modal'), options);
```